# How to plot text on plot for certain values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I started working on python and I am facing rough time because of the errors (for me) are not clear enough.

I am trying to plot stock market on matplotlib. The problem is that I either get the error `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars` or `the truth value of a series is ambiguous`. With the current code, I am getting the first one.

```
#create figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8),dpi=200)

axes1 = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1]) # Large figure

prices = data

#define width of candlestick elements
width = .4
width2 = .05

#define up and down prices
up = prices[prices["Direction"] == 1]
down = prices[prices["Direction"] == -1]

print(up.head())
print("-"*80)
print(down.head())

#define colors to use
green = 'green'
red = 'red'

print("-"*80)

print(up.info())

#plot up prices
for _, row in prices.iterrows():
    #here seems to be the error
    plt.text(x=prices.index, y=row["High"], s=row["KMeans_Labels"], rotation=90, color=green)
plt.bar(up.index, up["Close"]-up["Open"], width, bottom=up["Open"], color=green)
plt.bar(up.index, up["High"]-up["Close"],width2, bottom=up["Close"], color=green)
plt.bar(up.index, up["Low"]-up["Open"], width2, bottom=up["Open"], color=green)

#plot down prices
#for _, row in down.iterrows():
 #   plt.text(x=down.index, y=row["High"], s=row["KMeans_Labels"], rotation=90, color=green)
plt.bar(down.index, down["Close"]-down["Open"], width, bottom=down["Open"], color=red)
plt.bar(down.index, down["High"]-down["Open"], width2, bottom=down["Open"], color=red)
plt.bar(down.index, down["Low"]-down["Close"], width2, bottom=down["Close"], color=red)

#rotate x-axis tick labels
plt.xticks(rotation=90, ha='right')

#display candlestick chart
plt.show()
fig.savefig('figure.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

I think this might be because of, either the indexes or something similar. But I think that python errors are not clear enough.

**Edit:**

The error can be found on [this public site](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vSiW3ZSUWkdR0NybLAHYvFOoXL-5jfap3Bg3Urxwgsm3KhVhSdjCweND0cVX09JsWoDmwwkQW-e8Iaw/pub).
Says the error is:

1. `fig.savefig('figure.png', bbox_inches='tight')`

Also, if you want to run it, I [uploaded it into a public spot too](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zl7Yu2LoqHSwWAVHvcAU3e6zFB4i3dHa/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: When you get an error, it is extremely import to know which line (and preferably which part of that line) generates the error message. Adding the full error trace to your post will clarify a lot.  To help other help you, you'd also want to include reproducible data. Further, note that in `plt.text(x=prices.index, y=row["High"], ...)` the `x` is the complete index of a dataframe, while it should be just one x value.  Maybe you could try `for ind, row in prices.iterrows(): print(x=ind, y=..., ....)`?

Comment: Yep, you are right. Reposting all info I can gather.

Comment: I hope by "repost", you mean [edit] instead of creating a new question post.

Comment: So, did you try `for ind, row in prices.iterrows(): print(x=ind, y=row["High"], s=row["KMeans_Labels"])` instead of your current loop (`for _, row in prices.iterrows(): ...`)?

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot. But why did it? How to understand the errors that python give? Some lecture or something you would recommend in order to reduce the pain when getting any error? Like, how to solve it easier and faster?